# How to dynamically generate WSDL file and invoke the service?

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl

I'm looking for an example in C# how to programmatically create WSDL file based on XSD files where WSDL file contains 1 main XSD file, which contains several import directives to subsequent XSD files. After that WCF service should be invoked based on created WSDL file. The service contract is known.

I've spent a lot of time on internet trying to find something but no luck so far.

Comment: WCF is intended to work contract first, so why would you want to do that?

Comment: As I wrote input in our application were only XSD files that we're getting from our client. We should use those XSD files to generate through the code WSDL file. Generated WSDL file should then be used to call WCF service that has known operation contract: Message CustomAction(Message msg);

Comment: How can I create WSDL file from XSD files and service contract?

Answer (score 1):

There is a program that comes with .net sdk called wsdl.exe You could invoke this program using the methods of the Process class.

See this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/e8zac0ca.aspx

And this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok. But, what about using System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription and XmlSchemaSet classes?

Comment: I can't see how I can create WSDL file from XSD files and service contract.